# How to instal and run Apache solr in windows10

Tags: php, mysql, solr

I downloaded apache solr-5.2.1.zip. They said In this zip folder containing example folder in that start.jar through that we install. but in my download folder there is no such files but it have log4j file.

I want to install this solr  and work with php and mysql

If anybody have this experience share with me.

Answer (score 1):

start.jar is the pre-5.x way of doing things.

See [Running Solr](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Running+Solr) in the Solr Reference Guide.

The reference guide is a good place to start before asking very, very general questions on SO.

Comment: thanks for your link. I dont know how and where to chick and iam new to this work.

Comment: :) There is always a first time. Happy Learning